# How to test if an element has a structural directive

Tags: angular, jasmine

We created a simple structural directive to manipulate an element.

We use it this way:

`<div *hideUntilModalIsDisplayed></div>`

We would like, through tests, if the element apply the structural directive. Doing so, we ensure our tests would fail if someone  accidentally removes the directive.

We tried to make some tests on the element's `nativelement` but it doesn't work, of course (`element` being the `DebugElement`).

```
expect(element.nativeElement).toHaveAttr('hideUntilModalIsDisplayed');
expect(element.nativeElement).toHaveAttr('*hideUntilModalIsDisplayed');
expect(element.attributes.hideUntilModalIsDisplayed).toBeDefined();
expect(element.properties.hideUntilModalIsDisplayed).toBeDefined();
```

But every listed expects failed.

**What is the best way to test-secure a structural directive appliance on an element?**